# java.net.SocketPermission Access Denied Trendnet IP camera

Tags: java, camera, applet

I recently was forced to upgrade my Java version on Mac OS/X because it refused to run for "security reasons", so I have the latest Java (8 update 51). Then I tried to look at one of my old (2008) Trendnet TV-IP100 cameras. They have an option to see live video with activeX or Java, and Java has always worked fine. Until today, when first it refused to let me even load, saying it wasn't trusted. So I added the camera IP to the trusted sites list in the java security pane, and then it warned me but let me load the site, but of course it doesn't work anymore because of the apparently enhanced into uselessness new security.

I have read about what I think are solutions to this, if the applet was somewhere I could touch it, but it is inside a chip in the camera that is obsolete so editing it is not a simple matter. Is there any way I can ever get this to work again? I have a bunch of these cameras on various ports and IP addresses.

Update: I removed JRE 8 from my mac and installed 7.67 and the applet works fine again. Apparently the excessive security restrictions in JRE 8 prevent the old (ca. 2008) applet from working.

```
CacheEntry[ip address redacted/xplug.class]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969,length=16039
0
CacheEntry[ip address redacted/xplug$SI.class]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969,length=2436
CacheEntry[ip address redacted/xplug$TS.class]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969,length=2827
Exception in thread "Thread-16" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "5ip address redacted" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at xplug.run(xplug.java:332)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```